# How to get all documents from a collection without using StreamBuilder?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, document, stream-builder

I want to get all documents from firestore collection without using stream builder, otherwise I will have nested streams and in the last stream I am getting a null. Initial data is not solving my problem.

Now I make a stream builder for that collection, when a snapshot is chosen I jump on other widget and there I also make a stream builder and here is the problem.

I want to make stream builder only in the last widget of the scenario, because only there realtime data update is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use FutureBuilder with the following method

```
await Firestore.instance.collection("books").getDocuments()
```

Answer (score 2):

Get Realtime data using this:

```
 Firestore.instance
    .collection('books').snapshots().listen((querySnapshot){

});
```